# text editor find replace different words

Tags: mac, regex, text-editors, find-and-replace

Good evening

I have got a question about some text editor. I am using CotEditor on Mac and I want to find and replace something special. I have an .csv data which I converted as an .txt data with numbers. In this list there are some kind of special words which I want to find and delete all other words.

For example:

```
Going with fancy looking rig this week. **@aaw_sg** W500 CIEM, with gold and silver flakes, combined with @nullaudio cable and my faithful Shanling M5
```

or

```
If you are in Czech republic this week, be sure to visit Audio Video show Praha 2018. Shanling will be represented by our Czech distributor Gothic @headphones.cz in room 332 on 3rd floor. Visit audio-video-show.cz for more info
```

I want to filter all @*!

Background is I want to follow some tagged sites on Instagram and do not want to klick each pic and follow.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please clarify what you want to replace: do you mean the regular expression `@*!`, or all of the characters from the group `[@*!]`, or something else?

Comment: I mean all letters which begins at "@" and end with the next space.

Comment: The RE is "@[^ ]* ", which you replace with " " (no quotes in either case, but included here to delimit the strings). This will not remove "@string" at the end of a line if there is no trailing space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like `@\S+`.

Where:

- `@` means literally "@"
- `\S+` means 1 or more any character that is not a space.

**Edit according to comment:**

Using notepad++, you could do in one pass: (It also works in SublimeText)

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:^|\G)[^@]+(@\S+|$)`
- Replace with: `$1\n`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:     : non capture group
  ^     : beginning of line
 |      : R
  \G    : position of last match
)       : end group
[^@]+   : 1 or more any character that is not @
(       : start group 1
  @\S+  : @ followed by any non space character
 |      : OR
  $     : end of line
)       : end group 1
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1      : content of group 1
\n      : line feed, you could change it for the linebreak you need
```

**Result for given example:**

```
@aaw_sg
@nullaudio
@headphones.cz
```

Comment: Is it possible to see the opposite of what you suggested? Because your suggestion is doing the right way, but I only want to have all letters which begins at "@" and end with the next space.

For example:
From my first example there must only be:

'@aaw_sg @nullaudio'

My second example:

'@headphones.cz'

Comment: @SporeTinte049: I've updated my answer.

Comment: @SporeTinte049: You're welcome, glad it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the usage of your regex is Instagram account specific, `@[a-zA-Z0-9._]+` would be the find string.

cf. [Character Limit on Instagram Usernames -Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470180/character-limit-on-instagram-usernames)

#### regex for removing all non-account characters

The following two-step regex would remove all characters but leave Instagram accounts.

1. remove all non-account characters

   - find string: `(@[a-zA-Z0-9._]+|^)(.+?)(?=@|$)`
   - replacement string: `$1`
2. insert spaces between accounts

   - find string: `(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9._])@`
   - replacement sting: `@`

Comment: With your regex it shows what I wanna have, but what’s the regex for showing the opposite. I wanna find all the not Instagram account specifics and replace them with nothing

Comment: That's actually hard. I updated my original post. Do you mean something like this?

Comment: Yes, but when I tip the first bullet of "remove all non-account characters" and klick on replace all: everything is deleted!

Link for seeing the problem:

https://ibb.co/fakAFS
https://ibb.co/iuqcvS
https://ibb.co/hKBvh7

Answer (score 0):

In [**CudaText**](http://uvviewsoft.com/) editor (free) you can make new text file with @nnn accounts:

- call Find dialog, enter regex `@[\w\.]+`
- press "Select all" button
- copy selections to clipboard (Edit/Copy)
- make new tab, paste from clipboard (Edit/Paste)